# Angular 6 Cannot read property 'getScroll' of undefined

Tags: angular6

So far when I run my angular application , I got error below like that.

```
    at updatePosition (vendor.39816f62eefbe817c97e.js:1)
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.8b3031f6891125c33792.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.39816f62eefbe817c97e.js:1)
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.8b3031f6891125c33792.js:1)
    at t.runTask (polyfills.8b3031f6891125c33792.js:1)
    at t.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.8b3031f6891125c33792.js:1)
    at _ (polyfills.8b3031f6891125c33792.js:1)
    at m (polyfills.8b3031f6891125c33792.js:1)
```

**package.json**

```
   "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4"   //I already installed
     }
```

Comment: Make sure your not loading the module twice or including another script (which had zone as a dependency) twice.

Comment: above error with cause "Uncaught Error: Zone already loaded"